# how to select and group mysql data based on the following table

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum, case

### how can I achieve the desired result in mysql if my table looks like this.

### result|year

### 1     |2011

### 2     |2011

### 1     |2011

### 0     |2011

### 1     |2012

### 2     |2012

1 = Won, 2 = lost, 0 = draw

Every year can have multiple values like this. Not sure how I can get the desired result like below.

```
year  won  lost  draw  totalPlayed
2011  2     1     1       3
2012  1     1     0       2
```

I have tried the following query but does not get the desired result

```
select year,
league_types.league_name, 
sum(if(result = 1,1,0)) as won,
sum(if(result = 0,1,0)) as draw,
sum(if(result = 4,1,0)) as noResult,
sum(if(result = 2,1,0)) as lost, 
sum(if(result = 3,1,0)) as tied, 
sum(if(result > 0 and result < 4,1,0)) as played 
from match_score_card 
inner join fixtures on match_score_card.match_id = fixtures.match_id
inner join league_types on fixtures.league_id = league_types.league_id
where 
team_id = 1 group by year order by year desc
```

Comment: you must group by year, league_types.league_name as you use an agg function (e.g. sum())

Comment: tried with that as well but didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f03/10/0) that demonstrates the following query:

```
SELECT m.year,
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.result = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Won',
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.result = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Lost',
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.result = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Draw',
  COUNT(*) AS 'TotalPlayed'
FROM MyTable AS m
GROUP BY m.year
```

Comment: it works but as soon as I added inner joins to retrive other information about leagues from a different table it does the same thing again. not giving correct values.

Comment: problem here is each year can have different League types. e.g 2011 can have "League 1" and also "League 2".  League table looks like this league_id , league_name.

Comment: In your question you state *"how can I get the desired result like below"*.  Then you show a table that looks exactly like what is produced in the SQL Fiddle I linked.  Now you want something different?  Can you change your question to show the result of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that IF function in mySQL, but this standard SQL should work:

```
select year
     , league_types.league_name 
     , sum(CASE WHEN result = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as won
     , sum(CASE WHEN result = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as lost
     , sum(CASE WHEN result = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as draw
     , sum(CASE WHEN result = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as noResult
     , sum(CASE WHEN result = 1
                  or result = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as played
from match_score_card 
inner join fixtures 
on match_score_card.match_id = fixtures.match_id
inner join league_types 
on fixtures.league_id = league_types.league_id
where team_id = 1 
group by year, league_types.league_name
order by year desc, league_types.league_name
```

I'm guessing that you only want to count wins and losses as "played".